# Array of objects - has no method 'push'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a code which looks like:

```
var result = {};

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++)
{
  if(result.hasOwnProperty(questions[i].group)) {
    var questionsInGroup = result[questions[i].group];
    log.debug(typeof questionsInGroup);
    result[questions[i].group] = questionsInGroup.push(questions[i]);
} else {
    result[questions[i].group] = new Array(questions[i]);
}
```

Here I am trying to create an Associative Array where the keys are strings, and values are arrays of objects.

When I launch this code I get error:

```
result[questions[i].group] = questionsInGroup.push(questions[i]);
                                              ^
TypeError: Object 2 has no method 'push'
```

And debug message looks like:

debug: [node/server.js] number

Why the 'questionsInGroup' is a number if I have created it as Array:

```
result[questions[i].group] = new Array(questions[i]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`push` returns the new length of the array, not the array, so this line:

```
result[questions[i].group] = questionsInGroup.push(questions[i]);
```

...overwrites your reference to the array with a number. Simply remove the assignment.

---

Side note: It's generally best to avoid the `Array` constructor entirely (use `[]` instead), and it's **always** best to avoid it if you're calling it with just one argument. If you give the `Array` constructor a single argument that's a number, you'll get back an empty array with its `length` set to that number; but if you call it with any other type of argument, you get back an array with `length` of `1` containing that argument.

Example:

```js
var a;

a = new Array(2);
display(a.join(", ") + " (" + a.length + ")");

a = new Array("2");
display(a.join(", ") + " (" + a.length + ")");

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

For that reason, I'd replace:

```
result[questions[i].group] = new Array(questions[i]);
```

with

```
result[questions[i].group] = [questions[i]];
```